# How to check if a temporary table is existing in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am actually dropping a temporary table in Database. I have to delete only if it exists in the Database. Please let me know how to check if a table exists in Data base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#myTempTable') is not null
    drop table #myTempTable
```