# using Object_id() function with #tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ensure if a temporary table exists in my database or not.

I tried to use `OBJECT_ID()` function but it seems that I can't use it with temporary tables.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table CREATE TABLE #Table?

Comment: It's not a hash table, its a temporary table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a temporary table is existing in Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581427/how-to-check-if-a-temporary-table-is-existing-in-database)

Comment: @Nix - `@table` = table variable.  `#table` = temporary table.  `##table` = global temporary table.

Comment: Thank You all !
All the answers are write, now witch one will I Accept ?!

Comment: @Dems I dont understand your comment #table = temp table (as i said above) and its not a "hash table" that carries alternate meaning.

Comment: @nix - Oh, maybe you were replying to a comment or text that is no longer there.  I thought you meant `temporary table != #table`.  My apologies.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use

```
OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo')
```

to get the id for a temporary table when running in the context of another database.

Comment: I tried this : 
select OBJECT_ID('tempdb.myDb.##myTempTable') 
But, It's not working

Comment: Get rid of the `myDb` bit. That isn't in my answer! Use `OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##myTempTable')` or `OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##myTempTable')`

Comment: I know this is an OLD thread, but I just wanted to point out the fact that the answer has two (2) periods between tempdb and the #table...Took me a few tries to catch that.

Comment: yeah - if you created the temp table in non default schema you would put the schema name between those two dots

Answer (score 8):

When OBJECT_ID is called, for Temporary table/Hash table **TEMPDB** it must be specified unless it is already working database.

I check in SQL2008 and verify below.

```
USE SampleDB
create table #tt1 (dummy int)
select OBJECT_ID('SampleDB..#tt1')  -- returns NULL
select OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tt1')   -- returns ID
```

Answer (score 3):

From [SQL Server Codebook](http://sqlservercodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/check-if-temporary-table-exists.html)

```
How do you check if a temp table exists?
You can use IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
```

#### SQL Script

```
--Check if it exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
PRINT '#temp exists!'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT '#temp does not exist!'
END
```

Comment: You should at least quote your source ;)  http://sqlservercodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/check-if-temporary-table-exists.html

Comment: @Nix - True. *1 more character to type before SO allows me to post my comment :)*

Answer (score 2):

Use this to change the context of the OBJECT_ID call to tempdb

```
OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table')
```

OBJECT_ID [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) shows 3 part object names. In this case you can omit `schema_name`

> `OBJECT_ID ( '[ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ]`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of checking if the temp table exists.

The input id needs to be prefixed with tempdb as the database name, but the schema name also needs to be included or separated with a dot.

The following examples are validated

```
-- setup temp table
CREATE TABLE #Table (id INT NOT NULL)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Table') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Exists' -- using default schema
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Exists' -- using schemas in tempdb
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.sys.#Table') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Exists' -- using system view
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] LIKE '#Table%')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Exists' -- match any tables that starts with the same table id
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE LEFT([name], LEN('#Table')) = '#Table')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Exists' -- match any tables that starts with the same table id
END
```

If you want it to match unicode, prefix the input with an N

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#Table') IS NOT NULL
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Table') IS NOT NULL
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.sys.#Table') IS NOT NULL

IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] LIKE N'#Table%')
IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE LEFT([name], LEN('#Table')) = N'#Table')
```

The following examples will not work

```
IF OBJECT_ID(#Table) IS NOT NULL -- id not in single quotes
IF OBJECT_ID('#Table') IS NOT NULL -- tempdb name and schema not included
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.#Table') IS NOT NULL -- schema not included
IF OBJECT_ID('customdb..#Table') IS NOT NULL -- tempdb not indicated
```