# Issue dropping ##Table

Tags: sql, .net

.Net application runs a query that creates a global temp table ##Table1, i need the table to persist for a while as i sync the data to an external source over WCF. As part of my query i check to see if the table exists and drop before creating it, this is always returning 'table not exists', but when i query TABLE_NAME from tempdb.information_schema.Tables it shows ##Table1 as in there.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('##Table1') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE ##Table1
ELSE
PRINT 'Table Not Exists'
GO
select TABLE_NAME from tempdb.information_schema.tables
GO
```

This is always returning false?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401812/using-object-id-function-with-tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Table1')`